# How to create a class in itself which extended in PHP

Tags: php, class

It is simple, but hard to explain, let me give a shot:
What do I have to put to "???" to get correct results?
**How can I know that which class is final??**

***I need to solve it with "new" directive.***

```
class A {
    function create () {
        return (new ???)->name() ;
    }
    function name () {
        return 'ZERO' ;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function name () {
        return 'ONE' ;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    function name () {
        return 'TWO' ;
    }
}

class D extends C {
    function name () {
        return 'THREE' ;
    }
}

echo (new A)->create().'<br>' ; // ZERO
echo (new B)->create().'<br>' ; // ONE
echo (new C)->create().'<br>' ; // TWO
echo (new D)->create().'<br>' ; // THREE
```

Comment: `return $this->name() ;`

Comment: you are missing the point, I need final class name to create it, not that @u_mulder

Comment: What is `final` class?

Comment: B, C, or D... How root class can create extended class without $this?? because $this refers current class that created already!! I need a clean creation

Comment: There is a solution but it seems you are trying to solve the wrong problem. What's the point to create a new object and then discard it? Especially when you can use `return $this->name();` to get the behaviour you want?

Comment: Obvioulsy you don't understand how OOP works. Refer to manual please.

Comment: $this will create a new copy current created object!

Comment: `$this` will not create anything. __Please read a manual__

Comment: it is not same thing with "new", I need to use "new",

Comment: well, "new get_class($this)" worked, thank you anyway! @u_mulder

Comment: @Digerkam don't use `get_class`, read my answer. That's a clean solution.

Comment: but it is a working solution, why not to use? @vfsoraki

Comment: @Digerkam Because it is somehow considered as *metaprogramming*. Late static binding is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: it was just an hard to explain problem for me, not so lack of sense

Answer (score 1):

Modify `create` function to:

```
function create () {
    return $this->name() ;
}
```

Where `$this` is

> $this is a reference to the calling object

Comment: "calling object" means an object that already created, I need a clean creation

Answer (score 1):

you use `$this` for call same class function inside `class`

```
class A {
    function create () {
        return $this->name() ;
    }
    function name () {
        return 'ZERO' ;
    }
}
```

so it will work

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it this way.

This should work:

```
class A {
    function create () {
        return (new static())->name() ;
        # Or maybe better if you don't need the instance.
        # return static::name() ;
    }
    static function name () {
        return 'ZERO' ;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static function name () {
        return 'ONE' ;
    }
}

class C extends A {
    static function name () {
        return 'TWO' ;
    }
}

class D extends C {
    static function name () {
        return 'THREE' ;
    }
}

echo (new A)->create().'<br>' ; // ZERO
echo (new B)->create().'<br>' ; // ONE
echo (new C)->create().'<br>' ; // TWO
echo (new D)->create().'<br>' ; // THREE
```

Using `static` instead of `self` is called [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php).

Edit: On a second thought, you don't event need to define `name` methods as static. Using `new static()` is sufficient.

Edit2: I'm assuming you know when to use `static` methods and when to not. If you need more help on that, I can edit to explain it more.